# Answer always wrong even if it is right, Python

Tags: python

How do I match the answers from alist with my qlist? Whenever I try out the quiz, it always states wrong answer even if it is correct.. How do I solve it so that the questions matches with my answers? The matching of qlist and alist so that when one tries to answer, the answers obtained from alist matches with what the user inputs and confrims whether it is right or wrong. If it is right there will be marks awarded to the user. Thanks in advance!!

```
begin = raw_input ("Press enter to start...")
print " "


q1 = "Jack has 3 balls,\nMary has 5.\nHow many balls they have altogether?"

q2 = "What colour is Blue?\n \n(A) Brown\n(B) BLUE\n(C) coconut"

q3 = "What is 1 + 1 - 1?"

q4 = "What does a time watch do?\n \n(A) Takes you to the future\n(B) Donuts\n(C) Tell the time \nAll of the above"

q5 = "Who is the king of pop?(Micheal Jackson) \n(A) Hillary Duff \n(B) Mr. Jame \n(C) Mr. Sankar \n(D) Micheal Jackson"

q6 = "You see a person dying on the floor from getting shot, what would you do? \n(A)Help him out \n(B) Instagram \n(C) Give him a slice of pizza \n(D) PRAY TO THE CHICKEN MAN"

q7 = "Who is Frankenstein?\n \n" + "(A) DAD!\n" + "(B) Everyone at work\n" + "(C) A novel character\n" + "(D) THE CHICKEN MAN"

q8 = "Which side of your body is your left hand on, when you are looking in a mirror?\n" + "(A) Depends which side of the mirror you are looking at.\n" + "(B) left side\n" + "(c) right side\n" + "(D) Both sides"

q9 = "Jan is twice as old as her sister Betty, but half of Joe's age. Betty just got married. How old is Joe most likely to be?\n" + "(A) 56\n" + "(B) 84\n" + "(C) 1\n" + "(D)2000000"

q10 = "A green man lives in a green house. \nA blue man lives in a blue house. \nWho lives in the white house.\n" + "(A) white man\n" + "(B) black man\n" + "(C) brown man\n" + "(D) Obama"

qlist = (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10)

alist = ("8", "B", "1", "C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "B", "D")

n = 0
value = 0


for question in qlist :
    print question
    str.upper(raw_input(""))

if question == alist[n]:
    print "correct"
    Newvalue = value +10
    print " "
    print Newvalue
    print " "
else:
    print " "
    print "wrong"
    print " "
    n=n+1
```

Comment: What do you think went wrong? What specifically about matching are you having trouble with?

Comment: The matching of qlist and alist so that when one tries to answer, the answers obtained from alist matches with what the user inputs and confrims whether it is right or wrong. If it is right there will be marks awarded to the user.

Comment: Your presented indent is wrong - the check with `question` is *outside* the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not store the questions and answers in a single list?

```
qlist = [(q1, "8"), (q2, "B"), (q3, "1"), (q4, "C"), (q5, "D"), 
         (q6, "A"), (q7, "C"), (q8, "B"), (q9, "B"), (q10, "D")]
```

And then iterate over them like this:

```
for q, a in qlist:
    # q is the question, a is the correct answer
```

If you want to keep them as separate lists:

```
for n, q in enumerate(qlist):
    a = alist[n]    # gets the correct answer for current question
```

But I think putting them in a single list is simpler, because the question and answer are right next to each other. In fact, I'd just define the list directly, instead of having all your `q` variables.

Comment: Kindall, You are a major life savior!! Thanks a million!!! :D